# Powershell regex expression to extract class definition

Tags: regex, powershell

Using powershell, how do I write a regex expression that will extract the definition of a C++ class.

This powershell script

```
$source = 
    "class Node_A {               `n" +
    "public:                      `n" +
    "    Node_A();                `n" +
    "    int foo( int a ) {       `n" +
    "        return a * b;        `n" +
    "    }                        `n" +
    "    int b;                   `n" +
    "};                           `n" +
    "                             `n" +
    "class Node_B {               `n" +
    "public:                      `n" +
    "    Node_B();                `n" +
    "    int foo( int a ) {       `n" +
    "        return a + b;        `n" +
    "    }                        `n" +
    "    int b;                   `n" +
    "};                           "

$to_find = "(?sm)(class Node_. {[^;]+;)"
$source |
    select-string $to_find -AllMatches |
    foreach { $_.Matches } |
    foreach { $_.Value }
```

will find this

```
class Node_A {
public:
    Node_A();
class Node_B {
public:
    Node_B();
```

How do I make the script match `};` and not just `;`

Comment: honestly just look for an ast parser for c++ instead of doing this with regex?

Comment: To match up to a `};` you need to use `.`, not `[^;]`.

Comment: `(?ms)^class Node_. \{.+?^\};` perhaps. Still convinced you should do this with an AST parser.

Answer (score 0):

Following pattern would work for the string in question though as stated in comments, if you want a robust way to extract the classes you should look for a C++ AST Parser. Worth noting that since this is a multi-line regex pattern, the input **must be a multi-line string** otherwise it would fail. See https://regex101.com/r/0AoW8R/1 for pattern details.

```bash
$source | Select-String '(?ms)^class Node_. \{.+?^\};' -AllMatches |
    ForEach-Object Matches |
    Select-Object Index, Length, Value |
    Format-Table -Wrap
```

Using the input string in question, the output becomes:

```
Index Length Value
----- ------ -----
    0    212 class Node_A {
             public:
                 Node_A();
                 int foo( int a ) {
                     return a * b;
                 }
                 int b;
             };
  270    212 class Node_B {
             public:
                 Node_B();
                 int foo( int a ) {
                     return a + b;
                 }
                 int b;
             };
```